# Why exactly is this template function successfully compiling?

Tags: c++, templates, types, int, primitive-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Destructors of builtin types (int, char etc..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456310/destructors-of-builtin-types-int-char-etc)

Template Function:

```
template<typename T> void kill(T* type)
{
    type->~T();
}
```

Call:

```
int x= 5;
kill(&x);
```

woah, it compiled!? How can a primitive type like `int` have a destructor? It is also working with `char` , `bool` etc.

Comment: kill!!! I'm a homicidal maniac.

Comment: Okay--changed the `destroy` to `kill` above.

Comment: lol, I didn't notice that. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

§12.4.16 of the Standard says

> 16 [ Note: the notation for explicit call of a destructor can be used for any scalar type 
>   name (5.2.4). Allowing this makes it possible to write code without having to know if a 
>   destructor exists for a given type. For example,
>
> ```
> typedef int I;
> I* p;
> p->I::~I();
> ```
>
> —end note ]

Comment: so the compiler ignores any call to the destructor of a scalar type?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker whether it specially ignores them or just sees that they do nothing and leaves them out of the code, the effect is the same. It's a feature probably specifically meant for making it easier to write templates (though I can only guess; I don't know if this feature was there before C++ had templates). Also btw, your code exhibits undefined behaviour because the integer is destructed twice :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: There is no undefined behavior due to multiple pseudo-destructor calls. The only effect will be evaluation of expression before `.` or `->`. Moreover, there seems to be no UB for multiple calls of trivial destructors for the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part of the standard is §5.2.4/1:

> The use of a pseudo-destructor-name after a dot . or arrow -> operator represents the destructor for the non-class type named by type-name. The result shall only be used as the operand for the function call operator (), and the result of such a call has type void. The only effect is the evaluation of the postfix expression before the dot or arrow.