# Why bool doesn't have destructor?

Tags: c++, boolean, destructor

AFAIK, C++ offers destructors for primitive types for consistency reason. But that doesn't work for `bool` type.

```
bool*   vptr;
vptr->~bool();  // Error. "Expected a class name after '~' to name a destructor"

int8_t* vptr;
vptr->~int8_t(); // No error.
```

What's wrong with my code? Here's my compiler version.

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: "C++ offers destructors for primitive types" - no, it doesn't.

Comment: `int8_t` is not a primitive data type

Comment: User uk4321: 
I would comment that http://stackoverflow.com/a/456339/2925619 answers this question.

Comment: This is my fault of asking duplicated question.

Answer (score 7):

Because `bool`, like all other builtin types, is not a *class* type, though it works for typedefs and template arguments because the Standard allows it to enable generic programming.

```
template<typename T>
void destruct(T const & obj)
{
     obj.~T();
}
```

You can call this function for builtin types as well! :-)