# What is the effect of call to a trivial destructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, lifetime

Does a call to a trivial destructor end the lifetime of an object?
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217494/destructor-call-for-scalar-types-undefined-behavior) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000710/pseudo-destructor-call-does-not-destroy-an-object) but didn't find a good explanation. These threads state that a trivial destructor call has no effect and code like `struct A { int x; } a; a.~A(); a.~A();` is legal.
But I found that example in the standard:

```
struct C { };
void f() {
    C * pc = new C;
    using C2 = C;
    pc->C::~C2(); // OK, destroys *pc
    C().C::~C(); // undefined behavior: temporary of type C destroyed twice
    using T = int;
    0 .T::~T(); // OK, no effect
    0.T::~T(); // error: 0.T is a user-defined-floating-point-literal (5.13.8)
}
```

Here C has trivial destructor but still double destruction of an object of type C has undefined behavior?

Comment: You should never call destructors unless you've used placement new.

Comment: Good that you are asking. One of the valid effects of undefined behaviour is nothing happens, so you have to be wary. [Does this link clear anything up?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)

Comment: "Parsing issue" for `0.T` even if you don't provide `operator ""T`.

Comment: Rereading the question and re-reading the link, no the link won't help.

Comment: @user4581301 still does not answer my question. `However, if a program ends the lifetime of an non-trivial object explicitly, it must ensure that a new object of the same type is constructed in-place (e.g. via placement new) before the destructor may be called implicitly...` But what if the object is trivial? You say it's undefined, but I don't find anything on cppreference.

Comment: @Lassie What I *thought* was going on was undefined. Now I sit back and wait for someone who groks the standard, same as you.

Comment: You may want to add `language-lawyer` tag, although it looks to me like walnut already addressed the crux of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with C++20 trivial destructor calls end the lifetime of objects. Before that they did not and it was valid to call the destructor multiple times.

In C++17 (draft N4659) trivial destructors are explicitly excluded from ending the lifetime in [[basic.life]/1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#life-1.3) and objects with trivial destructor would live instead until their storage duration ends or their storage is reused ([[basic.life]/1.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#life-1.4)).

This was changed with the resolution of [CWG issue 2256](https://wg21.link/cwg2256) in [this draft commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/f3a6b2e671efdee5bacb74a5ea01d4bfb1900d3e).

Also note that *pseudo-destructor calls* also end the lifetime in C++20, but did not before that. Both questions you link in your question are talking about such pseudo-destructor calls. See the compatibility note against C++17 in [[diff.cpp17.basic]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/diff.cpp17.basic) of the draft (N4861).

Comment: @Lassie fixed it.