# Creation of simple types in c++

Tags: c++, object, types

I would like to know how are created the simple types objects (like int, bool, double,..). Is there any constructor called ? And Also, how are they destructed if there is no destructor ?

Comment: Your question shows no research effort at all. A valid question would be, if after your own research you do not understand some specific point.

Comment: Oh i m sorry but i searched but i didn't find any answer that's why i ask it here ? Maybe yuo could answer the question ? :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5113365/315052 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3803153/315052 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/456310/315052 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/24000710/315052

Answer (score 0):

Variables of type int, bool, double, char, etc. are NOT objects. These types are called primitive types, so no constructor/destructor outside of memory allocation/deallocation. Look them up for more details.

Answer (score 0):

They are not objects, in fact they are called primitive types.
Global and static variables are zero-initializated by default by the compiler.
Local variables usually contain a random value (it's not defined by the standard).