# How do I explicitly call the destructor of std iterators?

Tags: c++, std

Given `std::vector<A>::iterator` and `std::map<A, B>::iterator`, how do I explicitly call their destructors? I do not know the actual names of these types, because the `::iterator` member types are typedefs/aliases to implementation-specific classes.

I ask this question, because I am storing these iterators in an unrestricted c++ union and Visual Studio asks me to manually handle destruction. I *could* simply not call the destructor of the active element and assume iterators do not need clean-up, but that reeks of bad practice.

Comment: This smells like you are doing it wrong. But I don't know what you're doing, so I can't help you do it another, perhaps better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
// let iter be vector<int>::iterator to be destroyed
iter.std::vector<int>::iterator::~iterator();
```

> I do not know the actual names of these types, because the ::iterator member types are typedefs/aliases to implementation-specific classes.

Doesn't matter. Type aliases are type names as well.

---

LLVM appears to have a bug with this: https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=12350

Until it is fixed, as a workaround, introduce a non-nested alias:

```
using iterator = std::vector<int>::iterator;
iterator it;
it.iterator::~iterator();
```

or refer to the type as template argument (this code is from the bug report):

> ```
> template <typename T>
> inline void placement_delete(T *x) 
> {
>    // C++ lacks placement delete, so fake it with a function
>    x->~T();
> }
> ```

Comment: @RichardCritten appears to not be a problem according to standard: `The notation for explicit call of a destructor can be used for any scalar type name`

Comment: @StijnFrishert I think this is a clang bug. It appears to affect qualified nested type names - not type aliases. You can work around it with non-nested alias: https://godbolt.org/g/0TsBi7

Comment: @user2079303 thanks it does, going to ask a follow up question as it looks really strange. ... found a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000710/pseudo-destructor-call-does-not-destroy-an-object

Comment: @StijnFrishert I updated the answer regarding the bug.

Comment: @user2079303 Accepted this answer, because it follows the standard and the clang bug doesn't change that. Was about to file a report, good you found one already.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::destroy_at(&iter);
```

`std::destroy` and friends are a C+17 feature. If your compiler lacks support it is trivial to implement yourself:

```
template <typename T>
void destroy_at(T* p) {
    p->~T();
}
```

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at).

Comment: Very nice! Good to know this exists. So looking forward to widespread c++17 support!

Answer (score 0):

Most often iterator are nothing but pointer to already allocated memory. Unless the iterators are created using new

```
 typedef std::vector<A>::iterator VecIter;
 VecIter* iter= new VecIter;
```

there is no need to delete. If you are using new, then you can call delete explicitly for the iterator variable.

```
delete iter;
```

Comment: I am not talking about calling delete on an iterator, but explicitly calling its destructor. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t4fe76c.aspx#Anchor_3