# Primitive types as objects in c++

Tags: c++

I have come across the following piece of code and i couldn't understand what it means:

```
typedef int INT; 
5 .INT::~INT();
```

**Note:** There is a space between the numeric 5 and decimal.

**Questions:**
1. Could somebody explain what exactly does the two lines above mean?
2. Why would it not work without typedef? Any reason behind it?`5 .int::~int()` throws error.

Comment: @Hurkyl working fine for me : http://ideone.com/cc8PTn, try to compile it as .cpp

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/456339/2352671

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.INT::~INT()` is a **pseudo destructor call**, useful for templated code.

Note that it can't be used without the `typedef` type.

---

Standardese:

**C++03 §5.2.4 “Pseudo destructor call”:**

> 1. The use of a *pseudo-destructor-name* after a dot `.` or arrow `->` operator represents the destructor for the
>      non-class type named by *type-name*. The result shall only be used as the operand for the function call operator `()`, and the result of such a call has type `void`. The only effect is the evaluation of the *postfix-expression* before the dot or arrow.

Comment: But it is pointless in the given example, right? Can you elaborate what it could be possibly meant to here?

Comment: It's just a no-op. There is no cleanup for an `int`.

Comment: It's probably even undefined behavior in the example, given that `5` is a constant expression

Comment: @Hurkyl: Before the first standardization of C++, where the effective standard was the ARM (the Annotated Reference Manual by Stroustrup and Ellis), deleting via a pointer to `const` object was invalid. This was changed in C++98, the first standard, because it was impractical. Implicit destructor call on a constant object has always been valid and guaranteed, AFAIK. I am not sure about explicit destructor call on constant object. Sorry.

Comment: @Hurkyl For all I know, nothing in the Standard says that evaluating a pseudo-destructor-call with a constant expression as its LHS has UB. Additionally, there's [class.dtor]p2 *"A destructor can be invoked for a `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile` object. `const` and `volatile` semantics are not applied on an object under destruction. They stop being in effect when the destructor for the most derived object starts."* which does not specifically talk about *implicit invocation*, but generally about invocation of a dtor (but that's irrelevant here, since OP doesn't invoke a dtor).

Comment: +1 for this answer as well for the question because I learnt something new. One might also point to 7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple] for an explanation as to why it only works with the `typedef`, namely the fact that a *type-name* in the context of the standard can be a *typedef-name* but not an `int` type specifier.

Comment: I don't get the bit about the function call operator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's just the `()` parenthesis. I.e., *expr* `.INT::~INT` represents the destructor, and the only thing you can do with it is add a pair of parentheses `()`, a function call.

Comment: I've never heard of the function name being deemed an _operand_ of the function call operator, but okay.