# Providing specialization for templateed class method with two parameters (one being a non-type)

Tags: c++, reference-counting

Background information:   I'm on a microcontroller with a preference of pre-allocating as much as possible.    We've wrapped the RTOS with C++ objects that are easier to deal with and allow us to have different backings depending on the customer license needs (plus lets us provide a WinAPI implementation for unit testing on the host).

Anyways, given that, I have an RTOSQueue object that takes a type and # of elements:

```
template<typename T,unsigned elements>
class RTOSQueue
{
    T messages[elements];
public:
...
    RTOSError Send(T& message, bool bWaitIfFull=true);
    RTOSError Receive(T& message, bool bWaitIfEmpty = true);
}
```

And this is all fine, until I start to introduce reference counted objects to it.

```
template<typename T>
class shared_buffer : public buffer_interface<T>
{
    T*      m_pPtr;
    size_t  m_uElements;
    int*    count;
};
```

and use it as such:

```
RTOSQueue<shared_buffer<uint8_t>,10> MyQueue //10 element queue of shared buffers that handle uint8_t things

shared_buffer<uint8_t> MyBuffer(100); //A reference counted shared buffer of 100 bytes

MyQueue.Send(MyBuffer);
...
MyQueue.Receive(MyReceivedBuffer);
```

I want to increment the reference count on putting it into the queue, and decrement it on coming out.

The naïve approach was to just do assignments in `Send()` and `Receive()`.  It does the right thing on `Send()` (incrementing the count because there was a copy; the original goes out of scope and the count is decremented by 1), but Receive() doesn't (the copy stays in the pre-allocated queue element that gets recycled so it never gets decremented for that).   I clearly need to do something on the outgoing thing to 'clear out' the shared buffer in the queue storage, but because the code of the RTOSQueue is generic, it has to be something that works with other types as well.

I tried using `std::swap()` instead of assignments, and that works, but it's really odd semantics and you could end up with the references/count of the `shared_buffer<>` used to `Receive()` being put into the RTOSQueue storage and then never getting decremented until some time later when it's swapped out with an an incoming shared_buffer<> on `Send()`

I'd like to overload/specialize (I don't know) the Send/Receive functions to 'do the right thing' and twiddle the element the right way, except template syntax is beyond me.  The elements parameter to the RTOSQueue seems to make it difficult to overload for that type for all queue sizes.  Or maybe the type (shared_buffer) does.   Either way, I'm having trouble coming up with the incantation.

Help?

Comment: Generic code can still use `messages[i].~T();` to destroy objects in slots that are being emptied out. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/456339/23649

Comment: @jtbandes Almost.  Doing that does decrement the reference.  The issue then is when `Send()` comes to assign to it, it tries to decrement again using the (stale) pointers stored there.   I added a memset after the `~T()`, but it's starting to feel dirtier and dirtier.   EDIT:  oh, wait.  nvm, I can just zero out all the pointer members inside of ~T().

Comment: Are you keeping track (out-of-line) of which slots are used and which are not? If so, you can use `new (&messages[i]) T();` and `messages[i].~T()`. If not, you **must not** mix `messages[i].~T()` with `messages[i] = ...`. As you've noticed, that would be using `operator=` on an object after it has been destroyed.

Comment: @jtbandes   I eventually determined I couldn't deal completely in generics (I had no idea if a thing in the queue might not like being destructed).   I had to re-factor the entire queue class to where the number of elements wasn't in the same template layer as insert/remove so I could specialize the 'insert' and 'remove' per type.